# PageViewer ScrollledDown

Tags: android, view, scroll, android-viewpager

Im using a pageviewer but when i scroll the content(vertically) of pageviewer im not getting the call at either

```
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) 
    {
        android.util.Log.e("XXXX", "onPageScrollStateChanged");

    }
or
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) 
    {
        android.util.Log.e("XXXX", "Page Is scrolleed");

    }
```

but when i scroll the page horizontally im getting the call back at the above.any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewPager only holds the views. onPageScrollStateChanged and onPageScrolled are only called when pages are changed ie horizontal scroll only.

The vertical scroll is implemented by the view that you add to the ViewPager(using adapter). So add scroll listener to your child view(ie the view that you are adding to PageViewer).